# Capturing user response using Javascript confirm message from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind, scriptmanager

Currently I'm utilising `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to display javascript alert message to user in this way:

```html
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert Message", "alert('Save Successful!');", true);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to display a confirmation message to user, and retrieve either a 'Yes' or 'No' response from user. I know this can be done with: 
`MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;`

However windows confirmation message box always gets displayed behind and user often don't realize there's a message box being displayed.

How can I achieve this using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display a yes/no response, then process the result of that confirmation on the server, unless you postback to the server again, or call a web service and act on it via AJAX.

To follow up, answering yes/no triggers what within the page?

Comment: It's actually a delete button confirmation. If user clicks yes, the record will be deleted, and if user clicks no it's the other way round.

Comment: If you have to use registerstartupscript method, then you have to do another post back on confirmation response to process on the server.  You can trigger with __doPostBack